# force close, download file with asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

i have a running download function. but when i run it, like 80% of the time it make my phone laggy, force close, not responding for a very long time like 1~2 minutes. this case happened very randomly, i cant really trace what is the problem. the device will turn back to normally after the download is complete. i have tried on various devices such as galaxy S2, galaxy note, SE xperia Arc S, and few tables. problem remains the same. can anyone advice me how to improve my code? below is my existing code:

```
public void onClickDownload(View view){
        String url = "http://www.mydomain.com./" + fileURL;
        url = url.replaceAll(" ","%20");
        String sourceUrl = url;
        new DownloadFileAsync().execute(sourceUrl);
    }   

public class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {
        private boolean run_do_in_background = true;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... aurl) {
        int count;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
            URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
            conexion.connect();

            int lengthOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
            Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Lenght of file: " + lengthOfFile);

            File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MaxApps");
            boolean success = false;
            if (!folder.exists()) {
                success = folder.mkdirs();
            }
            if (!success) {
            } else {
            }

            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/MaxApps/" + apkURL);

            byte data[] = new byte[100*1024];

            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            total += count;             
            int progressPercent = (int) ((total*100)/lengthOfFile);
            if(progressPercent % 5 == 0){  
                publishProgress(progressPercent);
                }
            output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {

                notificationManager.cancel(Integer.parseInt(ID.toString()));

                Notification MyN = new Notification(); MyN.icon = R.drawable.logo1;
                MyN.tickerText = "Download Failed";
                MyN.number = 1;
                MyN.setLatestEventInfo (getApplicationContext(), apkURL + " Download Failed.", "Please try again", MyPI);
                MyN.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                MyNM.notify(1, MyN);    
                run_do_in_background = false;
            }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {          
        notification.contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.pbStatus, 100, progress[0], false);
        notificationManager.notify(Integer.parseInt(ID.toString()), notification);
        }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        if(run_do_in_background) {
        notificationManager.cancel(Integer.parseInt(ID.toString()));

        Notification MyN = new Notification(); MyN.icon = R.drawable.logo1;
        MyN.tickerText = "Download Complete";
        MyN.number = 1;
        MyN.setLatestEventInfo (getApplicationContext(), "Download Complete, Click to install.", apkURL, MyPI);
        MyN.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        MyNM.notify(Integer.parseInt(ID.toString()) , MyN);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't like very much that you update the notification in the onProgressUpdate because you execute those operations in the UI thread then you somehow block it.

Comment: how do you create and execute `DownloadFileAsync` object?

Comment: yes, i do create a new UI for my notificationbar to suit my need, then what should I do? is this cause the problem?
@Caner, check the update :)

Comment: how big is the file you are downloading?

Comment: @caner, from 50kb to 50mb.. 50kb cant really see the affect, because it can be done in just a blink.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that updating UI is taking long? Maybe you can try to test like this and see if it makes a difference:

```
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {          
    Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Progress: " + progress[0]);
}
```

By the way, this is not related to what you are asking, but I think you have problem in your code that handles the progress:

```
int progressPercent = (int) ((total*100)/lengthOfFile);
if(progressPercent % 5 == 0){  
     publishProgress(progressPercent);
}
```

That will update the progress only when it is exactly 5,10,15,20% etc... I guess you actually want to update progress when it is at least %5 further than before.

```
int previousProgress = 0;
while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
    total += count;             
    int progressPercent = (int) ((total*100)/lengthOfFile);
    if(progressPercent - previousProgress >= 5) {  
        previousProgress = progressPercent;
        publishProgress(progressPercent);
    }
    output.write(data, 0, count);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i have some question: what is actually the different between %5 with >=5? they just do the same thing right? the new calculation u provide looks like make the system do more work?

Comment: Assume that progress is constant and it is %6 each time. So it will go like this: 6,12,18,24,30,... Your code will update UI only when it is %30, 60%, 90%. My suggestion will update it each time and yes it is more work. But I just thought your code doesn't do what you intend to do. That suggestion is not related to your question..